# C# DataGridView get values from another column if cells is selected

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can i get A Column cell values, if B Column cells is selected ?

[image]

In this case: 14, 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
 private void datagridview1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (datagridview1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
   {
     foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
     {
       int selectedrowindex = cell.RowIndex;
       DataGridViewRow selectedRow = datagridview1.Rows[selectedrowindex];  
       string a = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[0].Value); 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I was try it and got this error: Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'DataGridViewCell.RowIndex'